# How to create "free" entry in outlook using Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, outlook

We use special library VEvent . For example:

```
VEvent event = new VEvent();
Duration duration = new Duration.Builder().hours(1).build();
event.setDuration(duration);
```

And other methods. This creates a "busy" calendar entry in outlook. How to create a "free" entry in outlook?

Comment: all non-busy time is free ) or what do you mean by "free" ? maybe you want to remove something from calendar?

Comment: I need to add the following property : X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE . But  to be honest I don't known about any methods that can do It

Comment: what is it: `special library VEvent` ? is it a public library ?